# Finding first matched string in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table as follows:

```
TABLE1

No  Description
1   Hello Hai Hello
2   Good Bad Good
3   Hello Good Hai
4   Hai Hello Bad
5   Hello Hello Hello
```

Now if I run the following query:

```
Select * 
from TABLE1 
where Description like '%Hai%' 
   OR  Description like '%Hello%' 
   OR Description like '%Good%'
```

I want the result as follows ( By adding one extra column "FIRST MATCHED WORD"):

```
No  Description     First Matched Word
1   Hello Hai Hello     Hai
2   Good Bad Good       Good
3   Hello Good Hai      Hai
4   Hai Hello Bad       Hai
5   Hello Hello Hello   Hello
```

Hear my intention is to find out the first matched word depends on our query. Kindly help me.

Comment: According to my understanding to your question, you want First Matched Word to be hai even if the description is having Hello first, since the query is having Hai first right?

Comment: Exactly. Since we are using Hai as a first word it should come first.

Comment: Then you can see my answer :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CASE statement` in `SELECT` query in following way:

```
Select No,Description, 
  CASE 
      WHEN Description like '%Hai%' THEN 'Hai' 
      WHEN Description like '%Hello%' THEN 'Hello'
      WHEN Description like '%Good%' THEN 'Good'
   END 
from TABLE1 
where Description like '%Hai%' 
   OR  Description like '%Hello%' 
   OR Description like '%Good%'
```

See [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5550/3)

`Case Statement` returns result of the first boolean expression that evaluates to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

If you want to add more words to match, you just have to add the word to the precedence table with a rank. If you  have large number of words to match , you can make the precedence table as a permanent table

```
with precedence as(
select 1 rnk, 'Hai' as word union all
select 2 rnk, 'Hello' union all
select 3 rnk, 'Good' ),
cte as 
    (select * 
     from Table1
     join precedence
     on  [Description] like '%'+word+'%' ),
cte1 as(select [No],[Description],word,
               ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [No] order by rnk) as row_num 
        from cte)
select [No],[Description],word from cte1 where row_num=1
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/302ae/1)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select *,'Hai' as 'First Matched Word' from Table1 where [Description] like '%Hai%'
union
select *,'Hello' as 'First Matched Word' from Table1 where [Description] like '%hello%' 
and [No] not in(select [No] from Table1 where [Description] like '%Hai%')
union
select *,'Good' as 'First Matched Word' from Table1 where [Description] like '%Good%' 
and [No] not in(select [No] from Table1 where [Description] like '%hello%' 
or [Description] like '%Hai%'
);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/871d5/20)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
      t1.No,
      t1.Description, 
      t2.Description AS matched,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t1.DESCRIPTION 
                            ORDER BY t1.DESCRIPTION) row_num
    FROM @TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT Description = 'Hai'
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT 'Hello'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Good'
    ) t2 ON t1.Description LIKE '%' + t2.Description + '%'
)
SELECT 
  No,
  Description,
  matched AS 'first matched word'
FROM CTE
WHERE row_num = 1
ORDER BY no;
```

### [Live Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84274/finding-first-matched-string-in-a-column-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case you can go for the if else statement like below,

```
if exists(select * from Table1 where description like '%Hai%')
begin
     update table1 set FirstMatchedWord = 'Hai' where No = @No
end
else
begin
     if exists(select * from Table1 where description like '%Hello%')
     begin
         update table1 set FirstMatchedWord = 'Hello' where No = @No
     end
     else
     begin
         if exists(select * from Table1 where description like '%Good%')
         begin
             update table1 set FirstMatchedWord = 'Good' where No = @No
         end
     end
end
```

Hope this helps :D